# UINavigationBarを配置すると上部に空きスペースができてしまう

Tags: swift, xcode

XCode11を使用しています。
UIViewControllerの上にUIViewを配置し、その上にUINavigationBarを配置したのですが、以下の画像のように上部に空白スペースができてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

UINavigationBarを上下に拡大・縮小する項目も見当たりません。
ページタイトルの表示位置としては今のままで良いのですが、上部の空白ができてしまうのだけが気になります・・・。
どうすれば上部に空白スペースを作らずにUINavigationBarを配置することができるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController`が表示するNavigation Barのように、ステータスバー部分を覆うように表示したいということで良いのでしょうか。

`UINavigationBar`を自前で配置するような画面は作ったことがなかったので、少し検索すると、以下のような記事が見つかりました。

[Navigation Bar Behind Status Bar](https://upte.ch/blog/extend-uinavigation-bar-behind-status-bar/)

図やコード例が詳しく載っているので、英語部分は読まなくても大体わかるかもしれませんが、記事中のコードは、storyboardを使用せずにコードで`UINavigationBar`を設置しているので、storyboardを使った場合に、最低限必要な部分を抜き出しておきます。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navigationBar.delegate = self
        //...
    }

    func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return .topAttached
    }

    //...
}
```

`UINavigationBarDelegate`のメソッド`position(for:)`を実装して`.topAttached`を返すようにする必要があるようで、storyboard上だけでの設定はできないようです。

なお、ステータスバー部分を完全に覆うようにするためには、`UINavigationBar`上端のSafe Area Topにぴったりくっつけておく必要があるようです。

[image: Storyboard]

Storyboardエディタ上での表示は変わりませんが、実行してみると、上部に広がって表示されているのがわかります。

[image: simulator]

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。望み通りの表示にすることができました！